# Model tree structure with aggregation in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I want to aggregate a model tree structure directly in mongodb database with Aggregations.

Is it possible to do hierarchical aggregations like that ? Currently, I do that in a program.

I want to use a collection like :

```
{
  "Name" : "john",
  "Parents" : ["sandy", "bryan"]
}

{
  "Name" : "sandy",
  "Parents" : ["bill", "daisy"]
}

{
  "Name" : "bryan",
  "Parents" : ["dora", "david"]
}

{
  "Name" : "dora",
  "Parents" : ["cliff", "darla"]
}
```

And generate a new collection like :

```
{
  "Name" : "sandy",
  "Parents" : ["bill", "daisy"],
  "Ancestrors" : ["bill", "daisy"]
}

{
  "Name" : "dora",
  "Parents" : ["cliff", "darla"],
  "Ancestrors" : ["cliff", "darla"]
}

{
  "Name" : "bryan",
  "Parents" : ["dora", "david"],
  "Ancestrors" : ["dora", "david", "cliff", "darla"]
}

{
  "Name" : "john",
  "Parents" : ["sandy", "bryan"],
  "Ancestrors" : ["sandy", "bryan", "bill", "daisy", "dora", "david", "cliff", "darla"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that use a MapReduce to do a tree structure aggregation is possible since MongoDb 2.4 because we can't use "db.mycollection.find(...)" in map functions.

So we can't retrieve hierarchicals documents in map functions...

> In MongoDB 2.4, map-reduce operations, the group command, and $where operator expressions cannot access certain global functions or
>   properties, such as db, that are available in the mongo shell.
>
> When upgrading to MongoDB 2.4, you will need to refactor your code if
>   your map-reduce operations, group commands, or $where operator
>   expressions include any global shell functions or properties that are
>   no longer available, such as db.